# Organizing multiple levels of Column Headers

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview

I have been trying to figure out how to make and move headers in a GridView now for a couple of days I have asked some questions with no replys.

I have managed to move abit futher on and i am going at things now a different way.

This is what i wanted to create:

[image]

I have now created the Heading 'Rota' and then below that create the days that are needed in my GridView, but I have 3 problems.

- My data is duplicating on the amount of rows I have.
- I need to move the 'Actual' and 'Expected' below the days.
- I need to get 1 - 23 to show below the hour label.

This is what i have so far:

[image]

As you can see that everything is getting duplicated when I just want the headers, also the Actual and Expected needed to be spreaded across T till S **(We need to keep the first hour label)** and finally i need to get the hours to show below the 'Hour' label.

HTML (So Far):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound">
                    <Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="M" ItemStyle-Width="30">
         <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lblMonday" runat="server" Text="Hour">
             </asp:Label>

         </ItemTemplate>
         <FooterTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</FooterTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="T" ItemStyle-Width="30">
         <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lblTuesday" runat="server" Text="T">
             </asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="W" ItemStyle-Width="30">
         <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lblWednesday" runat="server" Text="W">
             </asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="T" ItemStyle-Width="30">
         <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lblThursday" runat="server" Text="T">
             </asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="F" ItemStyle-Width="30">
         <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lblFriday" runat="server" Text="F">
             </asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S" ItemStyle-Width="30">
         <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lblSaturday" runat="server" Text="S">
             </asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S" ItemStyle-Width="30">
         <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lblSunday" runat="server" Text="S">
             </asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>


                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Required" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="70" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Actual" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="70" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

C# (So Far):

```
            GridViewRow HeaderRow = new GridViewRow(1, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);

        TableCell HeaderCell2 = new TableCell();
        HeaderCell2.Text = "Rota Data Schedule";
        HeaderCell2.ColumnSpan = 7;
        HeaderCell2.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
        HeaderRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell2);


        GridView1.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, HeaderRow);
```

**UPDATE**

I have managed to sort the layout of my GridView but the Gridview is still duplicating my data.

[image]

Here is my 'Fake' Data which is why i think my View is messing up:

```
  private DataTable GridData()
    {
        DataTable griddt;
        griddt = new DataTable();
        griddt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
        griddt.Columns.Add("Hour", typeof(int));

        DataRow griddr;

        griddr = griddt.NewRow();
        griddr["id"] = 1;
        griddr["Hour"] = 1;
        griddt.Rows.Add(griddr);

        griddr = griddt.NewRow();
        griddr["id"] = 2;
        griddr["Hour"] = 2;
        griddt.Rows.Add(griddr);

        griddr = griddt.NewRow();
        griddr["id"] = 3;
        griddr["Hour"] = 3;
        griddt.Rows.Add(griddr);

        griddr = griddt.NewRow();
        griddr["id"] = 4;
        griddr["Hour"] = 4;
        griddt.Rows.Add(griddr);

        griddr = griddt.NewRow();
        griddr["id"] = 5;
        griddr["Hour"] = 5;
        griddt.Rows.Add(griddr);

        griddr = griddt.NewRow();
        griddr["id"] = 6;
        griddr["Hour"] = 6;
        griddt.Rows.Add(griddr);

        griddr = griddt.NewRow();
        griddr["id"] = 7;
        griddr["Hour"] = 7;
        griddt.Rows.Add(griddr);

        griddr = griddt.NewRow();
        griddr["id"] = 8;
        griddr["Hour"] = 8;
        griddt.Rows.Add(griddr);

        griddr = griddt.NewRow();
        griddr["id"] = 9;
        griddr["Hour"] = 9;
        griddt.Rows.Add(griddr);

        griddr = griddt.NewRow();
        griddr["id"] = 10;
        griddr["Hour"] = 10;
        griddt.Rows.Add(griddr);

        griddr = griddt.NewRow();
        griddr["id"] = 11;
        griddr["Hour"] = 11;
        griddt.Rows.Add(griddr);

        griddr = griddt.NewRow();
        griddr["id"] = 12;
        griddr["Hour"] = 12;
        griddt.Rows.Add(griddr);

        griddr = griddt.NewRow();
        griddr["id"] = 13;
        griddr["Hour"] = 13;
        griddt.Rows.Add(griddr);

        griddr = griddt.NewRow();
        griddr["id"] = 14;
        griddr["Hour"] = 14;
        griddt.Rows.Add(griddr);

        griddr = griddt.NewRow();
        griddr["id"] = 15;
        griddr["Hour"] = 15;
        griddt.Rows.Add(griddr);

        griddr = griddt.NewRow();
        griddr["id"] = 16;
        griddr["Hour"] = 16;
        griddt.Rows.Add(griddr);

        griddr = griddt.NewRow();
        griddr["id"] = 17;
        griddr["Hour"] = 17;
        griddt.Rows.Add(griddr);

        griddr = griddt.NewRow();
        griddr["id"] = 18;
        griddr["Hour"] = 18;
        griddt.Rows.Add(griddr);

        griddr = griddt.NewRow();
        griddr["id"] = 19;
        griddr["Hour"] = 19;
        griddt.Rows.Add(griddr);

        griddr = griddt.NewRow();
        griddr["id"] = 20;
        griddr["Hour"] = 20;
        griddt.Rows.Add(griddr);

        griddr = griddt.NewRow();
        griddr["id"] = 21;
        griddr["Hour"] = 21;
        griddt.Rows.Add(griddr);

        griddr = griddt.NewRow();
        griddr["id"] = 22;
        griddr["Hour"] = 22;
        griddt.Rows.Add(griddr);

        griddr = griddt.NewRow();
        griddr["id"] = 23;
        griddr["Hour"] = 23;
        griddt.Rows.Add(griddr);

        griddt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { griddt.Columns["id"] };

        return griddt;
```

Comment: Excuse me, but I need to build my own understanding before I can help. I'd expect a grid more like found under [Wikipedia's Rota_(schedule)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rota_(schedule)) description. In your case, I would expect `Hour` to not be present as a name, and would expect `Expected` and `Actual` to be present under _each_ day. Can you give us a more detailed example (with filled in data) of what it is you are trying to show?

Comment: @MikeGuthrie Thanks for getting back. The Data will just be numbers with how may staff should be in that day and how many are actually in. I have edited my question as i have achieved the layout and now need to try and stop the grid from duplicating the data.

Comment: @MikeGuthrie I have drew a image at the top of my question. The Days across the top will click clickable and will change the data in the red box. The hours will be down the left. The image should explain at the top of my question.

Comment: The clickable days to populate the list is the part I was missing.  Making sense to me, now. Is there some requirement that is forcing you to make the days a part of the grid itself? Seems like this would be much simpler as its own element.

Comment: @MikeGuthrie I just need it to look like above, It doesn't really matter how to achieve it, I am just stuck at the moment with all the data duplicating. What do you suggest? It needs to be a GridView as when clicking a day it will bind data into the Grid.

Comment: Still working on this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this sample solution I've created for the layout you are after:

Aspx markup:

```
<div style="width:420px; text-align:center; border:1px solid black;">
    Rota Data Schedule
    <br />
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpDaysOfWeek">
        <ItemTemplate><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkDay" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("DayID") %>' OnCommand="DaySelect_Command"
                Font-Bold='<%# Bind("IsSelected") %>' Text='<%# Bind("DayAbbr") %>' Width="58" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1"
                style="margin:0 0 0 0;" BorderColor="Black" ForeColor="Black" /></ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvHoursAttendance" Width="420" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Hour" DataField="Hour" DataFormatString="{0:00':00'}" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Expected" DataField="ExpectedCount" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Actual" DataField="ActualCount" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

And the code-behind:

```
private DaySelect[] Days = new DaySelect[] 
    {
        new DaySelect() { DayAbbr = "M", DayID = 1, IsSelected = true },
        new DaySelect() { DayAbbr = "T", DayID = 2 },
        new DaySelect() { DayAbbr = "W", DayID = 3 },
        new DaySelect() { DayAbbr = "T", DayID = 4 },
        new DaySelect() { DayAbbr = "F", DayID = 5 },
        new DaySelect() { DayAbbr = "S", DayID = 6 },
        new DaySelect() { DayAbbr = "S", DayID = 7 },
    };

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rpDaysOfWeek.DataSource = Days;

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        rpDaysOfWeek.DataBind();
        gvHoursAttendance.DataSource = CreateWorkHours(Days.Single(d => d.IsSelected).DayID);
        gvHoursAttendance.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void DaySelect_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int dayId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    foreach (DaySelect day in Days)
    {
        day.IsSelected = day.DayID == dayId;
    }
    rpDaysOfWeek.DataBind();
    gvHoursAttendance.DataSource = CreateWorkHours(Days.Single(d => d.IsSelected).DayID);
    gvHoursAttendance.DataBind();
}

public WorkHour[] CreateWorkHours(int dayId)
{
    return new WorkHour[]
        {
            new WorkHour() { ActualCount = dayId, ExpectedCount = dayId, Hour = 0 },
            new WorkHour() { ActualCount = dayId, ExpectedCount = dayId, Hour = 1 },
            new WorkHour() { ActualCount = dayId, ExpectedCount = dayId, Hour = 2 },
            new WorkHour() { ActualCount = dayId, ExpectedCount = dayId, Hour = 3 },
            new WorkHour() { ActualCount = dayId + 1, ExpectedCount = dayId, Hour = 4 },
            new WorkHour() { ActualCount = dayId + 1, ExpectedCount = dayId, Hour = 5 },
            new WorkHour() { ActualCount = dayId + 1, ExpectedCount = dayId, Hour = 6 },
            new WorkHour() { ActualCount = dayId + 1, ExpectedCount = dayId, Hour = 7 },
            new WorkHour() { ActualCount = dayId, ExpectedCount = dayId + 1, Hour = 8 },
            new WorkHour() { ActualCount = dayId, ExpectedCount = dayId + 1, Hour = 9 },
            new WorkHour() { ActualCount = dayId, ExpectedCount = dayId + 1, Hour = 10 },
            new WorkHour() { ActualCount = dayId, ExpectedCount = dayId + 1, Hour = 11 },
            new WorkHour() { ActualCount = dayId + 1, ExpectedCount = dayId + 1, Hour = 12 },
            new WorkHour() { ActualCount = dayId + 1, ExpectedCount = dayId + 1, Hour = 13 },
            new WorkHour() { ActualCount = dayId + 1, ExpectedCount = dayId + 1, Hour = 14 },
            new WorkHour() { ActualCount = dayId + 1, ExpectedCount = dayId + 1, Hour = 15 },
            new WorkHour() { ActualCount = dayId * 2, ExpectedCount = dayId + 1, Hour = 16 },
            new WorkHour() { ActualCount = dayId * 2, ExpectedCount = dayId + 1, Hour = 17 },
            new WorkHour() { ActualCount = dayId * 2, ExpectedCount = dayId + 1, Hour = 18 },
            new WorkHour() { ActualCount = dayId * 2, ExpectedCount = dayId + 1, Hour = 19 },
            new WorkHour() { ActualCount = dayId - 1, ExpectedCount = dayId * 2, Hour = 20 },
            new WorkHour() { ActualCount = dayId - 1, ExpectedCount = dayId * 2, Hour = 21 },
            new WorkHour() { ActualCount = dayId - 1, ExpectedCount = dayId * 2, Hour = 22 },
            new WorkHour() { ActualCount = dayId - 1, ExpectedCount = dayId * 2, Hour = 23 },
        };
}

public class DaySelect
{
    public string DayAbbr { get; set; }
    public int DayID { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

public class WorkHour
{
    public int Hour { get; set; }
    public int ExpectedCount { get; set; }
    public int ActualCount { get; set; }
}
```

The key thing was to avoid so much customization on the grid. The Day-of-Week is used as a parameter for the data, but is not otherwise indicative of any columns of data in the grid. Simply move it out on its own, and let the grid show the data you are after -- attendance by hour.  (Note that if you still want `Hour`, `Expected`, and `Actual` to line up exactly with the day labels, you can provide explicit column widths, but I would recommend against it, because the days aren't really columns, they are tabs, so you would just be introducing confusion.)